# How To Import Eclipse Java Jar File To VSC?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, visual-studio-code

I created a maven project about api test in eclipse. I have to upload the this project to vsc. How can i do this?

Comment: The Java extension of VSCode is (a headless) Eclipse (wrapped as a language server). Just open the project, nothing have to be changed for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code is not an IDE but it's a code editor. So it doesn't have an import option. You can **Open** the folder of your maven application and for better integration you can download a visual studio code extension called **Maven for Java**.